# React tests with IndexedDB

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, indexeddb

I want to mock indexedDB for test purposes, I have declared in App.test.js:

```
const Dexie = require("dexie");
require("fake-indexeddb/auto");
const db = new Dexie("PersonsDB");
```

And in package.json:

```
 {
...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.2",
    "fake-indexeddb": "^3.1.3",
    "jest": "^26.6.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "fake-indexeddb/auto"
    ]
  }
}
```

After that - I'm getting an error:"These options (setupFiles) in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:" I don't want to force override it.

How can I configure Jest to work with indexedDB?

Answer (score 2):

I had to add in setupTests.js:

```
require("fake-indexeddb/auto");
```